# Cannot add new data

Tags: php

I am having issues adding some data to my DB. Down below I will post my code so far, there is something I'm probably missing but i don't understand what exactly.

I'm running this on my localhost using  PHP 7.0.9 but I don't think that matters.

This is on the Profile Page:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="row-form">
    <div class="col-lg-14"><strong>Title:</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-18"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"/></div>
</div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row-form">
    <div class="col-lg-14"><strong>Content:</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-18"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="content"/></div>
</div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row-form">
    <div class="col-md-14"><strong>Time:</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-18"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="time1"/></div>
</div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row-form">
    <div class="col-md-14"><strong>Date:</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-18"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="date1"/></div>
</div>

<div class="row-form">
            <div class="col-md-18"><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="author" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" /></div>
</div>
                                            <br>
<button name="addDates" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here's my PHP code :

```
<form method="POST">
    <?php

    require '@/config.php';
    if (isset($_POST['addDates']))
    {
        if (empty($_POST['title']) || empty($_POST['content']) || empty($_POST['time1']) || empty($_POST['date1']) || empty($_POST['author']))
        {
            $error = 'Please verify all fields';
        }
        if (empty($error))
        {
            $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES(NULL, :title, :content, :time1, :date1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), :author)");
            $SQLinsert -> execute(array(':title' => $_POST['title'], ':content' => $_POST['content'], ':time1' => $_POST['time1'], ':date1' => $_POST['date1'], ':author' => $_POST['author']));
            echo success('Date has been added');

        }
        else
        {
            echo error($error);
        }

    }

    ?>
</form>
```

Once i fill the forms and submit the page just refresh but nothing has been added on my side.

Comment: what errors messages

Comment: where is your `<form>` tag , also is your `php` code is on same page i.e profile page ?

Comment: Hello dean, I don't have any error messages, which is strange, because once i fill the blanks and submit, the page just refresh without getting to the point where it says "Date has been added".

Comment: @Swati Yes, the php code is on the same page, in my case Profile.php

Comment: remove the code above php code this one <form method="POST">

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` right below the require line to see what post contains, and then try some echo/dumping along the way to see how far it gets

Comment: including the action attribute to the form action=""

Comment: add <button type='submit'>Add</button> in button Tag.

Comment: Tried all of the given solutions but nothing yet so far. Speaking of which if i just submit the form without single given input, it should throw an error (on line 234) but it doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Remove if (isset($_POST['addDates']))

Comment: Removed the if check but nothing as of now

Comment: Guys, I have fixed the problem. I should've remove the "UNIX_TIMESTAMP()" when preparing to insert it.